# Test & datas - An issue with IDs

Tags: soql, unit-test, id

I'm working with class tests, I'm trying to use best practises so I got :
- one class I want to test
- one class for testing

I got a problem when inserting my datas :
@testSetup creates Accounts, and linked Contacts.

But they are not linked...
I think it's a particularity in tests (because of rollbacks or something like this), but I'm a noob on Apex, and in dev (only one year),

Could you point me what I'm doing wrong ?

Here are the classes :

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class AccountProcessorTest {
    @testSetup
    Public static void CreateSetSobjects() {
        // creating two account
        Account acc = new Account(Name='Acc Test 1');
        Account acc2 = new Account(Name='Acc Test 2');

        // Contacts for Acc - linked by accountId to acc.id
        Contact con = new Contact(LastName='Contact 1 pour Acc1', accountId=acc.id);
        Contact con2 = new Contact(LastName='Contact 2 pour Acc1', accountId=acc.id);
        Contact con3 = new Contact(LastName='Contact 3 pour Acc1', accountId=acc.id);

        // Contact for Acc2 - linked by accountId to acc2.id
        Contact conAcc2 = new Contact(LastName='Contact 1 pour Acc2', accountId=acc2.id);

        List<Account> lAcc = new List<Account>{acc, acc2};
        List<Contact> lCon = new List<Contact>{con, con2, con3, conAcc2};
        insert lAcc;
        insert lCon;
    }

    @isTest(SeeAllData=false)
    public static void AccountProcessor() {
        List<Id> lIds = new List<Id>();

        for(Account a: [SELECT Id, Name From Account]) {
            System.debug('AccountName : ' + a.Name);

            for(contact con : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE accountId = :a.id]){
                // I Can't enter THERE !
                System.debug('-------Contact lié : ' + con.name + ' -- ' + con.id);
            }
            lIds.add(a.id);
            System.debug('Liste rentree en test contient : ' + a.id);
        }
        Test.startTest();
        AccountProcessor.countContacts(lIds);
        Test.stopTest();

    }

    @isTest(SeeAllData=false)
    public static void printingEverything(){
        System.debug('TOTAL ACCOUNTS ' + [SELECT Id From Account].size() + ' Accounts.');
        System.debug('TOTAL CONTACTS ' + [SELECT Id From Contact].size() + ' Contacts.');

        for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts)
                           FROM Account]) {
            system.debug('Account name : ' + acc.Name);
            system.debug('Account Id : ' + acc.id);
            system.debug('-----------------------------ACCOUNTS');
        }
        for(Contact con : [SELECT Id, accountId, Name, account.name FROM Contact]) {
            system.debug('Contact Id : ' + con.id);
            system.debug('Contact accountId : ' + con.accountId);
            system.debug('Contact Name : ' + con.Name);
            system.debug('Account of the Contact : ' + con.account.name);
            system.debug('-----------------------------CONTACTS');
        }
    }
}
```

And the class to be tested :

```
public class AccountProcessor {
    @future(callout=false)
    public static void countContacts(List<Id> accIds) {
        integer count = 0;
        for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name
                           FROM Account
                           WHERE Id IN :accIds]) {
            System.debug('J\'AI EN BASE :' + [SELECT Id FROM Account].size());
            System.debug('J\'AI EN BASE :' + [SELECT Id FROM Contact].size());
            System.debug('Account : ' + acc.Name + ' id :' + acc.Id);
            System.debug('Account :' + [SELECT Id FROM Contact Where accountId = :acc.Id]);
            count = 0;
            // List<Contact> lCon = new List<Contact>();
            for(Contact con : [SELECT Id FROM Contact Where accountId = :acc.Id]) {
                count+=1;
            }
            // MAJ du field Number_of_Contacts__c
            acc.Number_of_Contacts__c = count;
        }
    }
}
```

I think I read something about Ids when testing, maybe I've to create fake Ids or something .. But I got back some Ids tho !!

This is a screenshot of my launching only the **printingEverything()** method

[image]

Thanks for your help,
Hopin' to be soon in that side of question / answers !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is, you have created an instance of account and then similarly Contact. But you have assigned the accountid from Account instance which was not yet inserted in the database and hence the id for it is not generated. The only thing you need to change is to insert the account before you assign the values to contact instance.

```
        Account acc = new Account(Name='Acc Test 1');
        Account acc2 = new Account(Name='Acc Test 2');
        List<Account> lAcc = new List<Account>{acc, acc2};
        insert lAcc;
        // Contacts for Acc - linked by accountId to acc.id
        Contact con = new Contact(LastName='Contact 1 pour Acc1', accountId=acc.id);
        Contact con2 = new Contact(LastName='Contact 2 pour Acc1', accountId=acc.id);
        Contact con3 = new Contact(LastName='Contact 3 pour Acc1', accountId=acc.id);
        // Contact for Acc2 - linked by accountId to acc2.id
        Contact conAcc2 = new Contact(LastName='Contact 1 pour Acc2', accountId=acc2.id);
        List<Contact> lCon = new List<Contact>{con, con2, con3, conAcc2};
        insert lCon;
```

One more thing I see in your code is You are using Query inside the for loop in class **AccountProcessor**. You will hit the governer limit and your apex class will get fail.

**Wrong way**

```
for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accIds]) {
        count = 0;
        // List<Contact> lCon = new List<Contact>();
   for(Contact con : [SELECT Id FROM Contact Where accountId = :acc.Id]) {
            count+=1;
   }
```

**Workaround:-**

What I am doing is subquery Contact on Account and getting the contact list related to each account using acc.Contacts.

```
for(Account acc : [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Contacts), Name FROM Account
                           WHERE Id IN :accIds]) {
            count = 0;
            for(Contact con : acc.Contacts ) {
                count+=1;
            }
          acc.Number_of_Contacts__c = count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why given code does not work is that account ids are assigned to contact records before they are actually specified.

To fix an issue, you need to insert account records first, so when you create Contacts, you provide related Account ids.

Please, check code below:

```
@testSetup
Public static void CreateSetSobjects() {
    // creating two account
    Account acc = new Account(Name='Acc Test 1');
    Account acc2 = new Account(Name='Acc Test 2');
    List<Account> lAcc = new List<Account>{acc, acc2};
    insert lAcc;
    // Contacts for Acc - linked by accountId to acc.id
    Contact con = new Contact(LastName='Contact 1 pour Acc1', accountId=acc.id);
    Contact con2 = new Contact(LastName='Contact 2 pour Acc1', accountId=acc.id);
    Contact con3 = new Contact(LastName='Contact 3 pour Acc1', accountId=acc.id);

    // Contact for Acc2 - linked by accountId to acc2.id
    Contact conAcc2 = new Contact(LastName='Contact 1 pour Acc2', accountId=acc2.id);
    List<Contact> lCon = new List<Contact>{con, con2, con3, conAcc2};

    insert lCon;
}
```

Comment: Well, I knew I was missing something... Thanks, I'll try now and come back to mark you answer !!

Comment: Ok !!
So it's because I have to INSERT contacts to make their Ids "being" ...
I'm tired, cause I already had this issue, I knwe I had to request it before using it ;

Thanks for you explanation !!